# How to play youtube video with videogular player

Tags: angular, videogular

i have some problem when play youtube video with videogular player.
How to play something on videogular player with link like that 
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJnBTPUQS5A".

For example this website : https://xemphimhayhay.com/video/1816/alan-walker-alone/

This is my code it have worked with mp4 file, can you tell me how to edit them to play with youtube link.

```
<div fxFlex>
<vg-player>
  <video [vgMedia]="media" #media id="singleVideo" preload="auto" controls>
      <source src="http://static.videogular.com/assets/videos/videogular.mp4" type="youtube">
  </video>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi. Have you found any solution? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Yes. I had already overcome this problem. This is my GitHub repo https://github.com/zymethyang/Jw-Player-angular-2